# Suitable Engine Oil grade for my car

Tags: engine, oil, maruti, alto

I have Maruti Alto LXI model car. its odometer 96000km. can I know whats the most suitable engine oil brand and grade for this??

Comment: Have you checked the owner's manual or the workshop manual?

Comment: As Solar Mike says your user manual should tell you the correct type and grade of oil to use - if you don't have your manual then we might still be able to help but you'll have to give us a bit more information - namely the year of the car and which engine it has.

Comment: [This post](https://www.mycarhelpline.com/index.php?option=com_easydiscuss&view=post&id=10628&Itemid=78) answers your question.  See [this image](https://www.mycarhelpline.com/images/Engine%20Oil%20Grade.jpg) from the post for recommend weight for a given driving temperature range.

Comment: What is the year of the car? What engine does it have?

Comment: Manufacture year 2003, it have 800cc engine. I checked the user manual and there is mentioned 20-40W oil grade as the recommended oil grade by maruti suzuki. is it okay...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the manual the recommended grade is 20W40 for that model and year.

Maruti Suzuki recommend various manufacturers oils - and offer co-branded versions under the following part numbers:

Castrol: 99999M20W40-CAS

Shell Helix: 99999M20W40-SHL

Total Quartz: 99999M20W40-TTL

Any of those will do the job.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, the right grade of oil for *any* engine is the thinnest oil which will develop adequate oil pressure after start-up.  Oil pressure develops as the pump forces the oil against the surfaces the oil lubricates; the major contributors are the main bearings.  If the engine's bearing tolerances are relatively tight, pressure will develop with a thinner grade of oil than they would with bearing tolerances that are loose.  As the engine wears, the tolerances loosen, and then typically a heavier grade of oil is needed to develop adequate pressure.  The grade specified by the manufacturer takes this into account, as well as known manufacturing tolerances and variations, and then attempts to achieve a compromise which will both satisfy a brand new, unworn engine, and one that has tens of thousands of miles/km on it.  Since part of any motor vehicle manufacturer's goal is to improve/maintain their reputation for durability, an eye to this is given when specifying a motor oil.  They also want to minimize warranty claims, and maximize fuel economy.  Thicker grades of motor oil protect the engine better, but as they increase the work the pump must do, they tend to contribute to lower fuel economy.

In short, it's a compromise.  Read more: https://www.machinerylubrication.com/Read/518/motor-oils